# long polling using JSON not working

Tags: java, javascript, json, jquery, client-server

I am trying to build chat application with long polling mechanism on Google app engine server.
HTTPRequest has default time out of 30 seconds, so I am sending polling request to server every 28 seconds if there is no update from server (so that I wont miss any message from other clients).
First request gets registered, but second request sent after 28 seconds is not reaching server.

```
function loadPage(query){
$.get({ url: query, success: function(events){
   updated = 1;
   //events data processing
   createServerChannel();
     });
}

  function createServerChannel(){
      var query='/ChatController?&user='+userName+'&sessionName='+sessionName+'&register=true';
      loadPage(query);
      updated = 0;
      setInterval(function() { poll(query); }, 28000);
   };

   function poll(query){
       if(updated==0){
          loadPage(query);
       }
   }
```

I am using thread.wait() for request to wait on server. Is there any way to consume first pending request when next request from same client is available.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think web sockets might be a better approach as this keeps a continuous connection open to the server and waits for the server to push data to the client.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/